# Deferred Promises with AJAX in Angular

Tags: ajax, angularjs, angular-promise

I'm trying to send data to my view from an AJAX call to my API. I am able to successfully hit my API and get data, but I was having problems with the view rendering before the AJAX call came back.

I'm trying to wrap my AJAX call in a Promise but it's not working. Here's my layout

**Controller**

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, Tweets) {
  $scope.tweets = Tweets.all()
})
```

**Factory doing ajax call**

```
.factory('Tweets', function($http) {
  $http.get('http://localhost:3000/tweets')
    .success(function(data) {
      var tweets = data
      debugger
  })

  return {
    all: function() {
      //should return the results of the AJAX call when it's complete
    }
  }
});
```

I've tried making wrapping the ajax call into a function and using .then(function(payload){ return payload.data }) - Payload.data has my data but its never returned when I call the function. I'm new to angular, so I would appreciate any help or insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define your factory as

```
.factory('Tweets', function($http) {
  return {
    all: function() {
      return $http.get('http://localhost:3000/tweets')
        .then(function(response) {
          return reponse.data;
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Then change your controller to

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, Tweets) {
  Tweets.all().then(function(data) {
    $scope.tweets = data;
  });
})
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was looking for. I've also seen a few other examples on the internets using ui-router resources to do something similar. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Yeah, @Klaster_1 answer is another option, if you define an object in routeProvider's resolve section, the object would be fetched before your controller initialization. You can keep the factory the same as my answer, and uses `resolve` as @Klaster_1 suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `$resource` service. The docs don't mention it, but comments in the source do.

> `$resolved`: `true` after first server interaction is completed (either with success or rejection), `false` before that.

So in the controller:

```
$scope.tweets = $resource('/tweets').query()
```

And in the view:

```
<div ng-if="tweets.$resolved">
```

Comment: Thank you. I like this method and was reading a bit about it but I'm unclear on where the address of my API is defined? Would I do it right in the resource query ```$scope.tweets = $resource('http://localhost:3000/tweets').query()``` ?

Comment: Only one way to find out, give it a go .. :)

Answer (score 1):

Loading data with [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource) or from factory promise callback are viable options, but there's one more way nobody mentioned yet: resolve data to controller via [route definition](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider). This approach allows to write simplistic controllers that don't know how to load data at all. In most cases it will be more than enough if you don't need to load data dynamically, like pagination or infinite scroll.

You will need to define route and resolve function:

```
angular
.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    controller: 'ctrl',
    controllerAs: 'view',
    templateUrl: 'view.html',
    resolve: {
      tweets: function (Tweets) {
        return Tweets.all();
      }
    }
  })
})
```

The `tweets` property on `resolve` will inject loaded data into controller as `tweets`, all you have to do is just assign received data:

```
.controller('ctrl', function (tweets) {
  this.tweets = tweets;
});
```

In addition, here's how `Tweets` service might look like:

```
.factory('Tweets', function ($timeout) {
  function all () {
    return $timeout(function () {
      return ["hey", "there"];
    });
  }
  return {
    all: all
  };
})
```

Basically, it exposes methods that return promise, returning some data ([$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$timeout) returns promise too, so I've used it instead of `$http` for example purpose).

[Full example on JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/heqakipipa/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Thank you! I've heard that most people using ui-router at this point, but I'm not sure why

Comment: ui-router provides more complex solution to views/routes, I was pleased to migrate to it on relatively big project from ngRouter. Anyway, you can resolve into controller in both routing modules.